# How to handle re-mapping of optional keys in function parameter

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I have a Clojure function with parameter: `[{:keys [from to]}]`. Both the `from` and `to` keys are optional. I would like to remap these keys into new keys but maintaining the values. What's an efficient/idiomatic way to go about this? Here's my curent solution.

```
(defn query
  [{:keys [from to]}]
  (let [re-map  {:$gte from
                 :$lt  to}]
    (into {} (remove #(nil? (val %)) re-map))))
```

I need it to return either one or both, and no nil if one of the key wasn't entered. So

```
=>(query {:from 10}) 
{:$gte 10}
```

and

```
=>(query {:from 10 :to 20})
{:$gte 10 :lt 20}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function for this in the [`clojure.set`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.set-api.html) namespace called [`rename-keys`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.set-api.html#clojure.set/rename-keys):

```
user=> (use 'clojure.set)
nil
user=> (rename-keys {:from 10} {:from :$gte :to :$lt})
{:$gte 10}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring for this:

```
user=> (defn re-map [{the-x :x the-y :y}] the-x)
user=> (re-map {:x 10 :y 1})  
10
```

I would recommend [this](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html) excellent introduction with lot of examples.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify that the return shouldn't have nil. Thanks!

Comment: It's really uncluear what you want to accomplish.
You say "I need it to return either one or both, and no nil if one of the key wasn't entered.", but this is exactly what simple "(defn fun [point] point)" does. E.g. "(fun {:x 10 :y 20}) => {:x 10 y :20}", (fun {:x 10}) => {:x 10}".

Comment: the choice is made at runtime